# Which of the following questions is grammatically correct:

Tags: grammaticality

Which of the following questions is grammatically correct:

Why didn't you deposit yesterday?

or

Why haven't you deposited yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

Neither is acceptable English ; they are incomplete.

"Deposit" is a transitive verb and thus usually requires a direct object although, given sufficient context, the direct object may be implicit rather than explicit.

Your second example has an additional error. When a specific past time is indicated, e.g., by "yesterday," the present perfect is not an appropriate tense.

Comment: We can write in this way
Why haven't you deposited?

Comment: As Jeff Morrow said, "deposit" is a transitive verb and it requires a direct object "money". I would say **"Why didn't you deposit the money yesterday?"** @Jeff Morrow If I'm wrong, please correct it.

Comment: As Raj said, you normally need to specify what was deposited, e.g, currency, a check, a suitcase, etc. If the sentence was part of a conversation where the object to be deposited was very clear, "Why didn't  you deposit" would be acceptable, but it would not be highly idiomatic. What would be far more likely is "Why didn't you deposit it/them."